# Using Geoserver ImageMosaic store with custom schema in postgis

Tags: geoserver, wcs

I'm trying to use the ImageMosaic data store to manage geotiffs that come from a range of vendors.  Using the indexer file, I was able to define a custom schema to populate some of the values but my goal is to have extra attribution that would get populated through a separate SQL process to build associations that you can use to run CQL_FILTERS with WMS.  My goal is to expose the granules using a CQL or FILTERING approach with WCS.  Is it possible to ingest imagery from a different location into the same data store with it's associated index table/schema?  I've looked at the `UseExistingSchema` parameter in the indexer but don't fully understand how this mechanism works.  If you want to add new granules to an existing ImageMosaic provider, do  you specify the target schema (e.g. Name=table_name) with the `UseExistingSchema=true` in the indexer.xml file?  Is there a way to set this up like a watch folder and then use the REST API to update the index?